# Filter a Sequelize instance

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Because of certain constraints in my API and because I prefer to keep the full scope of information on my model results, I would like not to filter the attributes of my query, but I would like to get certain attributes from an instance after the query has returned a value.

So instead of this:

```
User.findById(1, { attributes: ['firstName', 'lastName'] });
```

I would like to do something of the flavor:

```
const attributes = ['firstName', 'lastName'];
const user = await User.findById(1);
const displayUser = user.getAttributes(attributes);
```

By using some instance method on the query result itself ("getAttributes" in the example), I would like to specify the attributes that should belong to the display values of the instance.

I could not find any method that did this from the documentation (and doing a Search of the documentation).

Is this at all possible without defining an instanceMethod on the model?

**EDIT**:

I'm also well aware that I could just manually filter the results, but this doesn't seem like the ideal way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the solution, you can define a **toJSON** method in the instanceMethods, and specify the list of returned fields.

```
instanceMethods: {
    toJSON() {
        return {
            firstName: this.firstName,
            lastName: this.lastName
        };
    }
}
```

In different frameworks, toJSON is used by default when outputing the Sequelize instance.
It will work only if in your application before displaying the result you (or something for you) converting the instance to a plain object.